# Microsoft Identity how to update database to new table design

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have a webforms application written in asp.net v4.7 that uses Microsoft Identity which it created the relevant tables on our SQL Server.

We are now using Razor Pages with .NET Core for all new applications. I've created a new Razor Pages application and need to use Microsoft Identity once again with the same tables as the other applications. I've created the identity part but it comes up with an error that certain columns are missing from the tables on the SQL Server when I try to login.

I've tried using PM and doing an update-database but it comes up with an error saying the tables already exist. How do I update these tables to include the new columns that the latest Microsoft Identity needs please?

Many thanks

Comment: Sorry yes the razor pages application is using .NET core

Comment: are you using entity framework? if so, ```dotnet ef migrations add yourcomment``` and ```dotnet ef database update```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the asp.net core default identity table structure is not as same as asp.net's so there is no way to directly use the old table's data.

If you want to migrate from the asp.net to asp.net core identity, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Ah, I thought that might be the case as the naming of columns and additional columns are different between the 2 identity technologies. Out of interest, so I don't have to create a new database are we able to separate these out by schemas. ie: use CID.AspNetUsers instead of dbo.AspNetUsers.

Comment: It seems that the table format is not as same as identity , the asp.net core identity will contain the ASPNETROLECLAIMS and some new table.